# How to solve internet connection in ubuntu after upgrade failure

Tags: networking, relinux

I was trying to upgrade a Linux(Ubuntu) and the process went ahead correctly until power went off. Now i am trying to connect via my Ethernet and wireless but no connection.

What could be the problem with what I was doing?

Comment: If package installation was interrupted then some or many packages may be in an inconsistent state and “corrupted”. That includes kernel and kernel module packages (which in turn include device drivers among other) and the user space networking subsystem. There's a good chance of recovery but it may not be worth the effort compared to a re-installation that retains your personal files.

Comment: For a start, could you please include the output of `apt-get install -f`? in your question? You can [save the program output to a file](/q/420981/175814) and transfer that to a machine with internet access via an external drive.

Answer (score 0):

If the power failed when you were doing the upgrade, then your system is probably permanently broken.  There is only one practical way to fix it: back up your important files, and install Ubuntu from scratch.  See more information and instructions [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1946145).  Good luck.